# python recursion vowel count

Tags: python, string, recursion

```
def count_vowels(s):
    if not s:
        return 0
    elif s[0] in VOWELS:
        return 1 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    else:
        return 0 + count_vowels(s[1:])
```

I see that this code works perfectly fine for finding the number of vowels in a string. I also understand recursion always calls for a base case. I guess my main problem with this code is what does the first if statement actually mean? What is it checking?

```
if not s:
    return 0
```

if what not s? Is there any way to write the code without that portion?

Answer (score 2):

This is your exit from recursion. Your recursion has to stop at some point of time (otherwise it will run forever).

It means that if the string is empty - return 0 (there are no vowels in empty string) and stop.

Answer (score 1):

`if not s` checks if the string is empty. Empty strings are "false-y" objects in Python. If the string is empty, it must not have any vowels.

I realize you are probably required to use recursion here, but this would be a better way to do it in practice:

```
>>> VOWELS = set('aeiou')
>>> def count_vowels(s):
...     return sum(x in VOWELS for x in s)
... 
>>> count_vowels('hello world')
3
```

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. Yes for loops seem more ideal than recursion at this point but such is the assignment.